# Proper structure for Gradle multi-module builds with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I have a Kotlin project which is comprised of three modules:

```
Core < Service < Web
```

The structure is:

```
build.gradle
core/
    build.gradle
service/
    build.gradle
web/
    build.gradle
```

The structure for the root `build.gradle` file is:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

The individual build files look like (for `core`):

```
dependencies {
    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

And for `service` (note the only difference is the project dependency):

```
dependencies {
    compile project (':core')
    // Kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

There are a few optimizations I'd like to make, but I'm still learning Gradle, and can't find the right way to reorganize things. *The problems I have are:*

1. I can't build `service` or `web` individually, as they complain about not being able to find their dependent sub-projects. (Via a `gradle build` in the `service/` directory, for example.)
2. How can I define the Kotlin `stdlib-jre8` dependency at the root level, so it's not duplicated in my three build files?
3. How can my subproject/buildscript tasks of the *root buildfile* use the same repository definitions, so that I don't have to define `mavenCentral()/jcenter()` twice?

Basically this build structure that I have was cobbled together through some experimentation/web resources, and **happens to mostly work**, but I'd like some guidance on doing it the right way, such that (1) it follows good Gradle practices, and (2) still works well via auto-import into IDEA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want to run a build on a module you can do by running: `gradle :web:build`
2. In the same way that you are adding repositories in the `subprojects` clause, you can add the `dependencies` block in there. Make sure that only the shared dependencies are in there. For instance, `compile project(':core')` should only be in the relevant project. It's ok to have multiple `dependency` blocks. That said, it's usually more of a headache to use the `subproject` clause. Because, if dependencies change for one of the modules you are forced to update that for all of them
3. Regarding the `repository` definitions, they are very different. The one in the `buildscript` block is used by Gradle itself in order to find plugins and other 'pre-build' requirements. The one on the submodules is used to find the dependencies of the source code in the given module. As mentioned on the previous point, it's easier to manage when placed on the respective module build scripts.

## Update:

If you want to keep the same version for all modules, the variables defined on `ext` in the buildscript should be able to be accessed from the submodules too: `ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.60'` and if you have multiple ones you can add them like:

```
ext {
  kotlin_version = '1.1.60'
  junit_version = '4.12'
}
```

Also, if you want to share code between modules, you can always extract it to gradle file and load it where needed using: `apply file: "$rootDir/path/to/script.gradle"`

Regarding #3, I'll give you a practical example.

Google has its own maven repository that contains all the dependencies for an android module. If you have a project that contains both a server-side module and android module you may not need the server-side one to look up dependencies on the Gradle artefact repository (artefact is the name of the jar dependency).

As for the `buildscript` repositories, in your case you are only loading one classpath (pre-build) dependency which is located on `mavenCentral()` so you may be ok removing `jcenter()` here.

Comment: Thank you! #1 works great, as does #2. I actually like keeping the projects on the same dependency version, for example JUnit - when a new version comes out, I always want the latest. Further, I can't see a case where I want two modules on *different* Kotlin runtime versions. Per #3, I now understand the difference between the two sections - and will keep them both. But it still seems like a good idea to keep the build repository in the root.

Comment: @CraigOtis Updated in the response